Projection that varies point by point is an open map
Let us consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^6=\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3$ and let us represent any vector as $(x,y)$, with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^3$. For fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, let $y^\perp$ be the orthogonal projection of $y$ to the hyperplane perpendicular to $x$. Now, consider the map $\pi:\mathbb{R}^6\to\pi(\mathbb{R}^6)=:Q$ defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pi(x,y):&=(x,y^\perp), \text{ if }x\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}\\
\pi(0,y):&=(0,0).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I would like to prove that $\pi$ is an open map. It is kind of a projection and I know projections are open maps, but the problem here is that the target subspace depends on $x$. 
Some tools from vector bundle technology could help. Maybe one can prove that $\pi:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^3\to\pi(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a vector bundle.
This question is linked to Planes attached point by point produce plane bundles.

The codomain of $\pi$ is $\Bbb R^6$ because you said so, and there's zero chance of this map being open. If you want to know if $\pi:\Bbb R^6\to\pi(\Bbb R^6)$ is open (id est onto its image), then it's another story.

Yes, probably the subset topology of $\pi(\mathbb{R}^6)$ is the right one.

$\pi(\mathbb R^6)$. And what do you mean by "probably"?

Because I am not sure, the problem I am studying is a little bit different. But once I solve this, I can solve mine. However, yes I need openness on the image.

First of all, you need to remove the origin from the first $\Bbb R^3$. Then consider $p\colon\Bbb R^3-{0}\to S^2$ and the tautological $2$-plane bundle $E\to S^2$ (whose fiber over $x$ is the plane orthogonal to $x$). Then $\pi\big((\Bbb R^3-{0})\times\Bbb R^3\big)$ is the total space of $p^*E$. You can locally trivialize this and check your claim easily enough.

I was looking exactly for something like this. Thank you @TedShifrin

With $p$ you mean the stereographic projection?

@TedShifrin could you argue your comment, maybe with an extensive answer?

Radial projection, not stereographic.

@TedShifrin Yes, sorry I mean the map$ x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|}$.

@TedShifrin using your advice, I only managed to prove that $\pi(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}\times\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the total space of the pullback bundle $\pi_1:\pi(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}\times\mathbb{R}^3)\to\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}$ via the radial projection $p:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}\to\mathbb{S}^2$ of the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{S}^2$. How to transmit these information to the domain $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}\times\mathbb{R}^3$?

Over an open hemisphere (resp., open halfspace in $\Bbb R^3$), say $x_3>0$, trivialize $E$ (resp., $p^*E$) by projecting onto the plane $x_3=0$. Then in this trivialization, your map $\pi$ is a standard projection, hence open.

P.S. Thinking of $E$ as the tangent bundle of the sphere is really not helpful. Stick with the simple geometry as I said it.

For sake of completeness, I will answer to my question, as I think to have proven the openness of $\pi$ by definition. If my proof is wrong, please let me know.
Indeed let consider the basis of the topology of $\mathbb{R}^6$, $\{\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2)\}_{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^6}$, where $\mathbb{B}_{x}(r)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^3:||y-x||<r\}$. Let us prove that for any $x=(x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^6$,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    \pi(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))=\pi(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2^\perp}(r_2))=(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2^\perp}(r_2))\cap Q.
\end{equation}
This would prove that the map $\pi$ is open w.r.t. the relative topology of $Q$, as all the open sets of a basis of the topology are mapped into relatively open sets.
Claim 1: suppose $(x_1,x_2)\in Q$, then
$$
\pi(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))=(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))\cap Q.
$$
$\supset\big)$ Let $y\in(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))\cap Q$, then $y=\pi(y)\in\pi(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))$.
$\subset\big)$ Let $y\in \pi(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))$.
By construction $y\in Q$, moreover let $y=(y_1, y_2)=\pi(z)$, with $z=(z_1, z_2)\in \mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2)$, $z_1=y_1$ and $z_2^\perp=y_2$, then
\begin{align*}
    ||y_1-x_1||&=||z_1-x_1||<r_1,\\
    ||y_2-x_2||&=||z_2^\perp-x_2^\perp||=||(z_2-x_2)^\perp||\leq||z_2-x_2||<r_2,
\end{align*}
where we have used that $x_2=x_2^\perp$, since we have assumed $x\in Q$ and that the map $x_2\mapsto x_2^\perp$ is a orthogonal projection, hence linear and a contraction. This proves Claim 1.
Now, let us prove the first equation. So, consider any $x=(x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^6$. 
$\supset\big)$ Let $y\in (\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2^\perp}(r_2))\cap Q$ and let $z=(y_1, z_2)$, such that $z_2^\perp=y_2$ and $z_2\in B_{x_2}(r_2)$, then $\pi(z)=y$ and $z\in \mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2)$. 
$\subset\big)$ Viceversa, let $y=\pi(z)\in \pi(\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2}(r_2))$, with $z_1=y_1$ and $z_2^\perp =y_2$, then $y\in Q$, by construction and
\begin{align*}
    ||y_1-x_1||&=||z_1-x_1||<r_1,\\
    ||y_2-x_2^\perp||&=||z_2^\perp-x_2^\perp||=||(z_2-x_2)^\perp||\leq||z_2-x_2||<r_2,
\end{align*}
so $y\in (\mathbb{B}_{x_1}(r_1)\times\mathbb{B}_{x_2^\perp}(r_2))$.
Still, if one has a proof of the openness of the map (on neighborhood of points with non-zero first vectors) through vector bundles, it is well accepted.
